# Difference between the curly and round brackets for propositions in a theorem

Tags: lean

I'm very confused by the use of braces for propositions in a theorem. See the following four snippets:

```
theorem contrapositive_1 : ∀ (P Q : Prop),
  (P -> Q) -> (¬ Q -> ¬ P) := sorry

theorem contrapositive_2 (P Q : Prop) : 
  (P -> Q) -> (¬ Q -> ¬ P) := sorry

theorem contrapositive_3 : ∀ {P Q : Prop},
  (P -> Q) -> (¬ Q -> ¬ P) := sorry

theorem contrapositive_4 {P Q : Prop} : 
  (P -> Q) -> (¬ Q -> ¬ P) := sorry
```

I thought, they were all the same, but clearly they are not, because when I want to use `contraprositive_1` and `contraprositive_2` in the proof of another theorem, `lean` shows an error for type mismatch:

> term h1 has type P → Q : Prop but is expected to have type Prop : Type

On the other hand, `contraprositive_3` and `contraprositive_4` work fine.

What is the difference between the curly and round brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is whether the argument is explicit `()` or implicit `{}`. In general, you want arguments to be explicit, unless they can be figured out from arguments that come later. For example

```
lemma foobar {X : Type} (x : X) : x = x := sorry
```

In this case `X` is implicit, because once you tell Lean about `x`, it can figure out `X` itself (it is the type of `x`). In other words, if you want to apply the lemma to `y : Y` you can just write `foobar y`.
If instead you would make

```
lemma quux (X : Type) (x : X) : x = x := sorry
```

you would have to call it as `quux Y y`.

If you place an `@` before a name you turn all the implicit arguments into explicit arguments. So you can call `@foobar Y y`. “Conversely” if you want Lean to figure out `Y` by itself you can write an underscore: `quux _ y`.

The relevant section in TPIL: https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/dependent_type_theory.html#implicit-arguments

Answer (score 1):

- Arguments in **()** brackets is what you need to pass to the function yourself.

  > These are so called explicit arguments.
- Arguments in **{}** and **⦃⦄** brackets are figured out by Lean's
  **unification system**.

  > We use **{}** when Lean can deduce { argument } to the function based on ( another argument we provided ). **{}** and **⦃⦄** differ in timing of the unifier.
- Arguments in **[]** brackets are figured out by Lean's **type class inference system**.

  > We use **[]** when Lean can deduce [ argument ] based on facts from mathlib.

---

A good article on brackets in Lean by Kevin Buzzard: [https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/xena/formalising-mathematics-2022/Part_B/brackets.html](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/formalising-mathematics-2022/Part_B/brackets.html).